# Using forcats with data that has possible levels not present in data

Tags: r, forcats

My data has levels that are theoretically possible but not present in the data. I can easily represent this in `base` R:

```
factor(c("test","test1","test2"), levels = c("test","test1","test2","test3"))
```

If I table it, I see that `test3` is 0. This is great and allows for the possibility that I can write functions assuming these levels include all possible outcomes in case data is eventually added that includes this level.

I can not replicate this in `forcats`. First off, the `as_factor` function does not accept any additional arguments:

```
forcats::as_factor(c("test","test1","test2"), levels = c("test","test1","test2","test3"))
```

The above produces an error.

The following works with a warning (which I would prefer to accomplish my goal without warnings, if possible):

```
forcats::as_factor(c("test","test1","test2")) %>% forcats::fct_recode(`test` = "test", `tests` = "test1", `tests` = "test2", `tests` = "test3")

Warning message:
Unknown levels in `f`: test3
```

Is there any way in `forcats` to play with levels that theoretically exist but are not necessarily in the data at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to replicate the same behavior with `factor`, may be use `fct_expand`

```
c("test","test1","test2") %>%
       forcats::fct_expand(c("test","test1","test2","test3"))
#[1] test  test1 test2
#Levels: test test1 test2 test3
```

---

Regarding the use of `...` (other arguments in `as_factor`), it is not actually used

```
library(forcats)
methods(as_factor)
#[1] as_factor.character* as_factor.factor*    as_factor.logical*   as_factor.numeric*
```

Now, we check the code of `as_factor.character`

```
getAnywhere(as_factor.character)
function (x, ...) 
{
    structure(fct_inorder(x), label = attr(x, "label", exact = TRUE))
}
```

The `fct_inorder` takes only the 'x' and not any other arguments passed in with `...`

Here, we can use `fct_expand` directly to expand the `levels` of the `factor` or `character` (converts to `factor`)

Comment: Works great! see my solution below where I have implemented your suggestion. Let me konw if you have any additional improvements . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per the advice of @Akrun, I have accomplished what I was seeking to do. See an example below:

```
test <- c("fruit","fruit","apple","drink","meat")
levels <- c(
  `Fruit` = "fruit",
  `Fruit` = "apple",
  `Drink` = "drink",
  `Vegetable` = "vegetable",
  `Meat` = "meat"
)

factor(test) %>% table()
factor(test) %>% forcats::fct_expand(levels) %>% table()
factor(test) %>% forcats::fct_expand(levels) %>% forcats::fct_recode(!!!levels) %>% table()
```